# Existence of normalizable solution in specific system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, wavefunction, normalization

Suppose we have some function $\Psi(x,y)$ satisfying

\begin{align}
&\partial_{x} \partial_{y} \Psi(x,y)=0 \\
&(\partial_{x}^2 - \partial_{y}^2) \Psi(x,y)=0.
\end{align}

Then how can we determine $\Psi(x,y)$ is normalizable or not?

Comment: Depends on boundary conditions

Comment: This seems overspecified as a wavefunction - i.e. one equation too many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at what these conditions say about the second derivatives of the function. Taking the Hessian in the form
$$H=\begin{bmatrix}\partial_{xx}\Psi & \partial_{xy}\Psi
\\ \partial_{xy}\Psi & \partial_{yy}\Psi\end{bmatrix}$$
you set the cross term to $0$ by the first condition and set the diagonal elements to equal by the second one. So the only allowed Hessian is isotropic everywhere! There is only one such (twice differentiable) function (up to scaling and translation):

$$\Psi(x,y)=A((x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2)+B$$

And this one is not bounded (thus not normalizable), unless $\Psi(x,y)=0$ which is also not normalizable for a different reason.